# Where can I find a tutorial on setting up a secure mail server?

Tags: mail-server

Is there somewhere a good tutorial on how I can set up a secure mail server with Ubuntu server?

I'd like to try it so I can do some practice with Linux system administration.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of Digital Ocean tutorials that have been well received:

[How to run your own mail server with mail in a box on Ubuntu 14.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-run-your-own-mail-server-with-mail-in-a-box-on-ubuntu-14-04)

[How to install and setup postfix on Ubuntu 14.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-setup-postfix-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: Thanks, can this also be a good one : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MailServer I know its old but as far as I can see it teach me everything I need to know about  virusses and grey-listing and some other tricks

Comment: What about this serie : https://blogging.dragon.org.uk/mail-server-on-ubuntu-16-04-part1/